# itoa implementation crashing?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I am trying to implement atoi in assembly (the netwide assembler). I have verified that my approach is valid by inspecting the register values with a debugger. The problem is that the application will crash when it is about to exit. I am afraid my program is corrupting the stack somehow. I am linking against the GCC stdlib to allow the use of the printf function. I noticed it mutated the registers which caused unexpected behaviour (extensive iterations over values I did not recognize), however I solved this by storing the value of EAX inside EBX (not modified by printf) and then restoring the value after the function call. This is why I have been able to confirm that the program now behaves as it is supposed to by singlestepping through the algorithm AND confirm that the program crashes as it is about to terminate.
Here is the code:

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .data

_str: db "%d", 0

section .text

_main:
mov eax, 1234
mov ebx, 10
call _itoa
_terminate:
ret

_itoa:
test eax, eax
jz _terminate
xor edx, edx
div ebx
add edx, 30h
push eax
push edx
push _str
call _printf
add esp, 8
pop eax
jmp _itoa
```

And here is the stackdump:

> Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=00402005
>   eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=20000038 edx=61185C40 esi=612A3A7C edi=0022CD84
>   ebp=0022ACF8 esp=0022AC20 program=C:\Cygwin\home\Benjamin\nasm\itoa.exe, pid 3556, thread main
>   cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
>   Stack trace:
>   Frame     Function  Args
>   0022ACF8  00402005 (00000000, 0022CD84, 61007120, 00000000)
>   End of stack trace

EDIT: Please note that the stackdump really is not that relevant anymore as the program no longer crashes, it just displays an incorrect value.

Comment: Note that the code above is not crashing. The OP asked a question, and then changed the question after they got an answer. This makes it harder for people searching the web to find solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your platform, but I would expect you need to restore the stack by popping off the pushed values after calling `printf()`.

Since `printf()` doesn't know how many arguments will be passed, it can't restore the stack. Your code pushes arguments that are never popped off. So when your procedure returns, it gets the return address from the data that was pushed on the stack, which are not going to point to valid code. And that would be your access violation.

Comment: I am using Windows and Cygwin as my toolchain, sorry because I forgot to mention :) And I just tried popping those two values and it didn't help.

Comment: You really aren't providing enough information. You should've put your small bit of code in your original question and not require navigating to another site. And now I can only guess what your new code looks like. Also, I don't know how many bits you are working with. How many bytes is the pointer to `_str`?

Comment: I am using Pastebin because SO always messes up when I try to put my code in code tags. This is a 32-bit program. And I messed up your advice about popping those two values. It's now done correctly, and the program no longer crashes, but still displays an incorrect value (52515049). I will now edit the question.

Comment: Yes, I saw a number of problems with your code. Please do not edit the question. Please mark my answer as accepted, and create a new question if you have a new issue.

Comment: The number you show is exactly what you told it to do! You might want to try telling `_printf` to display a character. Then you should see "4321"... as expected.